# How to add red circles next to items in QTreeView (breakpoint style)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside2, qtreeview

I have something like this:

[image]

I can't show you more, but this is a simple `QTreeView` with `QStandardItems` in it. The items in the figure have a parent item which has a parent item as well.

When I activate the **breakpoint** on a item I have this:

[image]

which is ok but I also would like to add a **circle** next it as the majority of IDEs do (I took as example *PyCharm*):

[image]

The problem is that I have no idea how to do it. Anyone can help?

Comment: From the last image it looks like you want the circle to be shown in the vertical header rather than as part of the associated item -- is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to override the `drawRow` method of QTreeView and use the information from the QModelIndex to do the painting:

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from PySide2.QtGui import QColor, QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QApplication, QTreeView

IS_BREAKPOINT_ROLE = Qt.UserRole + 1


class TreeView(QTreeView):
    def drawRow(self, painter, option, index):
        super().drawRow(painter, option, index)
        if index.column() == 0:
            if not index.data(IS_BREAKPOINT_ROLE):
                return
            rect = self.visualRect(index)
            if not rect.isNull():
                margin = 4
                r = QRect(0, rect.top(), rect.height(), rect.height()).adjusted(
                    margin, margin, -margin, -margin
                )
                painter.setBrush(QColor("red"))
                painter.drawEllipse(r)


def main(args):
    app = QApplication(args)
    view = TreeView()
    view.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    model = QStandardItemModel()
    model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["col1", "col2"])
    view.setModel(model)
    counter = 0
    for i in range(10):
        item1 = QStandardItem("Child 1-{}".format(i))
        item2 = QStandardItem("Child 2-{}".format(i))
        for j in range(10):
            child1 = QStandardItem("Child {}-1".format(counter))
            child2 = QStandardItem("Child {}-2".format(counter))
            child1.setData(counter % 2 == 0, IS_BREAKPOINT_ROLE)
            item1.appendRow([child1, child2])

            counter += 1

        model.appendRow([item1, item2])

    view.show()
    view.resize(320, 240)
    view.expandAll()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose an alternate solution based on the [answer by eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67176074/2001654), which adds a left margin to the viewport, avoiding painting over the hierarchy lines (which could hide expanding decoration arrows for parent items that still need to show the circle).

Some important notes:

- the left margin is created using `setViewportMargins()`, but all item views automatically reset those margins when calling `updateGeometries()` (which happens almost everytime the layout is changed), so that method needs overriding;
- painting on the margins means that painting does not happen in the viewport, so we cannot implement `paintEvent()` (which by default is called for updates on the viewport); this results in implementing the drawing in the `event()` instead;
- updates must be explicitly called when the scroll bar change or items are expanded/collapsed, but Qt only updates the region interested by items that have been actually "changed" (thus possibly excluding other "shifted" items); in order to request the update on the full extent we need to call the base implementation of *QWidget* (not that of the view, as that method is overridden);

```
class TreeView(QTreeView):
    leftMargin = 14
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.leftMargin = self.fontMetrics().height()
        self.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.updateLeftMargin)
        self.expanded.connect(self.updateLeftMargin)
        self.collapsed.connect(self.updateLeftMargin)

    def updateLeftMargin(self):
        QWidget.update(self, 
            QRect(0, 0, self.leftMargin + self.frameWidth(), self.height()))

    def setModel(self, model):
        if self.model() != model:
            if self.model():
                self.model().dataChanged.disconnect(self.updateLeftMargin)
            super().setModel(model)
            model.dataChanged.connect(self.updateLeftMargin)

    def updateGeometries(self):
        super().updateGeometries()
        margins = self.viewportMargins()
        if margins.left() < self.leftMargin:
            margins.setLeft(margins.left() + self.leftMargin)
            self.setViewportMargins(margins)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == event.Paint:
            pos = QPoint()
            index = self.indexAt(pos)
            qp = QPainter(self)
            border = self.frameWidth()
            bottom = self.height() - border * 2
            qp.setClipRect(QRect(border, border, self.leftMargin, bottom))
            top = .5
            if self.header().isVisible():
                top += self.header().height()
            qp.translate(.5, top)
            qp.setBrush(Qt.red)
            qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
            deltaY = self.leftMargin / 2 - border
            circle = QRect(
                border + 1, 0, self.leftMargin - 2, self.leftMargin - 2)
            row = 0
            while index.isValid():
                rect = self.visualRect(index)
                if index.data(IS_BREAKPOINT_ROLE):
                    circle.moveTop(rect.center().y() - deltaY)
                    qp.drawEllipse(circle)
                row += 1
                pos.setY(rect.bottom() + 2)
                if pos.y() > bottom:
                    break
                index = self.indexAt(pos)
        return super().event(event)
```